# Get Indexpath of UiTableView header?

Tags: ios, uitableview

Is there any way I can get indexpath of uitableview's header?

I have following code:

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
    LocationCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil){
        [NSException raise:@"headerView == nil.." format:@"No cells with matching CellIdentifier loaded from your storyboard"];
}
```

As in above delegate method, there is no indexPath is passed, can I get the indexpath of header?

Comment: you can get the indexPath in tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath method,

Comment: Do you mean the indexPath.section for header?

Comment: Anbu: I can't get the didSelect to be called when I tap header cell. anhtu: No, the indexpath.

Comment: To my knowledge header doesn't have any indexPath stuff, since it's just a single view.

Comment: You Can Create Array Of Header Title And Put Button to Header And Ganrate Click Action Of Their Button So You Can simply Set Tag And when you  Click Button Get Tag Like IndexPath

Comment: If you want your header view to be tappable then you will need to add you will need to add your own UITapGestureRecognizer to the header view.

Answer (score -2):

The section header (or footer) in a `UITableView` does not have a property indexpath, however it does provide access to the current `section` in the delegate method you show in your question.

Refer to the Apple Documentation for table view headers and footers under [UITableViewHeaderFooterView](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewHeaderFooterView_class/index.html) Class Reference.